# Error while checking if URL is exists in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, url, uri

I want to check that the url exists or not.

Fuction:

```
Future _checkUrl(String url) async {
  http.Response _urlResponse =  await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  if (_urlResponse.statusCode == 200) {
   return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Call:

```
_checkUrl("https://stackoverf").then((value) => {
  print(value)
});
```

It works when I give `https://fonts.google.com/?category=Sans+Serif` (returns true) or `https://stackoverflow.com/qu` (returns false).

But when I try with `https://stackoverf` which is not valid, it gives me `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'stackoverf' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)`.

How to make `_checkUrl` returns false with this call?

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception instead of leaving it unhandled?

Comment: REFER HERE: [URL CHECK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69335358/how-do-i-check-whether-an-url-link-exists-and-get-statuscode-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for what you want?

```
Future<bool> _checkUrl(String url) async {
  try {
    http.Response _urlResponse =  await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    return _urlResponse.statusCode == 200;
    // return _urlResponse.statusCode < 400 // in case you want to accept 301 for example
  } on SocketException {
    return false;
  }
}
```